# an embeddable Java ETL

Tags: java, etl

I'm looking for an embeddable Java ETL, an Extract Transform Load engine that can be called from Java code.sample code may be useful to help me specific to extraction.
thunks

Answer (score 3):

[Scriptella](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/) is a good candidate, embedd and straightforward.

[Data Pipeline](http://northconcepts.com/) in another option (not free version).

[Smooks](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) maybe worthwhile too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/)? You'll find API usage examples here: 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+-+Java+API+Examples

Comment: thunk you.am not good in english.i use Talend and i want to know where  can integrate a code of security(encryption...)